# Declare a compiler check-able array of common property names of two unrelated types

Tags: typescript

I'm using TypeScript 2.9.2. I have a class:

```
class Class1 {
    public prop1: number;
    public prop2: number;
    public prop3: number;
}
```

I declared an `ReadOnlyArray` representing a subset of `Class1` keys:

```
private readonly keysSubset: ReadOnlyArray<keyof Class1> = ["prop1", "prop2"];
```

Now, I want to declare a variable which can take any of property names declared in `keysSubset`:

```
const someKey: ? = this.keysSubset[1];
```

I don't want to give it neither `string` type, nor manually enumerate possible values like this:

```
const someKey: "prop1" | "prop2" = this.keysSubset[1];
```

I want to explicitly say "this can contain any value from `keysSubset`", so when items in `keysSubset` gets changed statically in the code (not at the run-time), I don't have to change `someKey` type declaration manually and compiler still could check whether `someKey` is assigned one of the values from `keysSubset`.

**UPDATE** (To give more info on the rationale):
I need the exact type for `someKey` to iterate over `keysSubset` and update some properties of instance of a different class `Class2` from an object of type `Class1`:

```
class Class2 {
    public prop1: number;
    public prop2: number;

    private readonly keysSubset: ReadOnlyArray<keyof Class1> = ["prop1", "prop2"];

    public updateFrom(source: Class1): void {
        this.keysSubset.forEach((someKey: ?/*keyof Class1 won't work since Class2 doesn't have prop3*/): void => {
                this[someKey] = source[someKey];
            });
    }
}
```

So in short, the problem I'm solving is updating a given subset of properties of `Class1` from an instance of a different type `Class2`. While subset is static, there is some generic logic for each property update, so I don't want just write a bunch of `class1[someLey] = class2[someLey]` statements.

How to declare the type of `someKey` in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the type of `keysSubset` is an array of all keys in the class. This is what we need to change first, so that the type of `keysSubset` is exactly an array of the assigned values. We can use a helper function for that, while still constraining the values to be keys of the class.

To get the type of an item in an array we can use a type query.

```
class Class1 {
    public prop1: number;
    public prop2: number;
    public prop3: number;
}
// Helper function to infer the subset of keys correctly 
function keyArrayOf<T>() {
    return function <K extends keyof T>(o: K[]) {
        return o;
    }
}

class Foo {
    // will be inferred as  ("prop1" | "prop2")[]
    private readonly keysSubset = keyArrayOf<Class1>()(["prop1", "prop2"])
    method(){
        // Use a type query to get the type of an item of the keysSubset array
        const someKey: Foo['keysSubset'][number] = this.keysSubset[1]; // "prop1" | "prop2"
        // Or just let inference work
        const someKeyInffered = this.keysSubset[1]; // "prop1" | "prop2", no need for an explicit annotation 
    }
}
```

**Edit**

Your updated example could be written using the `keyArrayOf` helper function as:

```
class Class2 {
    public prop1: number;
    public prop2: number;

    private readonly keysSubset = keyArrayOf<Class1>()(["prop1", "prop2"])

    public updateFrom(source: Class1): void {
        this.keysSubset.forEach((someKey: Class2['keysSubset'][number]): void => {
            this[someKey] = source[someKey];
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a plan, but could you take a look at the updated question? How can we declare an exact type for `someKey`? This is my linter requirement.

Comment: I think the idea to have a rule to force you to specify ALL types is not a very good one... some types are horrible to write, The compiler already has the option of `noImplictAny` to prevent inference where the compiler can't infer the type.

Comment: @AlexanderAbakumov also if `Class2` is a subset of `Class1`, maybe just declare `keysSubset` as `(keyof Class2)[]` ?

Comment: Yes, specifying all types feels painfully in the beginning, but after a while you realize how many production bugs those explicit type declarations help to prevent. TypeScript is all about typing in the end of the day :) From this experience, when you catch yourself in writing a horrible type declarations, you already know that you're doing something that should be simplified\decomposed at least for readability in the future. I hoped TS has something simple for this case, similar to `keyof`, but for `Array` values.

Comment: This is the exact problem: `Class2` is not just a subset of `Class1`. That's why I'm trying to use an `Array` which keeps common properties.

Comment: @AlexanderAbakumov I don't necessarily agree with this all explicit school of thought, but it's your call. If you don't want any inference then `keyArrayOf` is of limited use to you and you need to explicitly type your array to `("prop1" | "prop2")[]`. The limited use of `keyArrayOf` is to ensure that the strings are actually keys of `Class1`

Comment: Please take a look at my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51867537/3345644). I think it's a good way to avoid manually specifying `("prop1" | "prop2")[]`.

Answer (score 0):

*(**@TitianCernicova-Dragomir**'s [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51862629/3345644) contains a direct answer to my initial question. This answer contains an answer to **how to declare a compiler check-able array of common property names of two unrelated types**. Thanks to @Titian, I realized that I was thinking backwards: I don't need to create a union **type based on a constant string array values**. I need a union **type consisting of common property names from `Class1` and `Class2`** in the first place. Then, I'd be able to declare an array of that type. So, the below contains the answer to this problem.)*

### TLDR

Here is how to declare a type containing ONLY common properties from two other types:

```
type CommonProperty = keyof {
  [P in keyof Class1 & keyof Class2]: Class1[P] | Class2[P]
}
```

Now you're able to declare an array containing a desired subset of common properties which will be checked by the compiler for correctness of values:

```
const keysSubset: ReadOnlyArray<CommonProperty> = [
        "prop1" // Ok,
        "prop2" // Ok,
        "prop4" // Error - property is missing in Class1
    ];
```

### Step by step:

First step on the way is to understand how to declare a type containing ONLY common properties from types `Class1` and `Class2`:

```
type CommonFromClass1AndClass2 = {
  [P in keyof Class1 & keyof Class2]: Class1[P] | Class2[P]
}
```

That was the most complex part for me.

Now we can declare a string union type representing subset of common property names:

```
type CommonProperty = keyof CommonFromClass1AndClass2;
```

And finally, we can use it in an array declaration:

```
const keysSubset: ReadOnlyArray<CommonProperty> = [
        "prop1" // Ok,
        "prop2" // Ok,
        "prop4" // Error - property is missing in Class1
    ];
```